# Merging of API response data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, rxjs

I am currently working on a React.js full stack application with Express back-end. I had a question regarding a design decision for the API calls. I have 3 APIs at the moment

**GET /airports/**

```
{
   "total_count":269,
   "items":[
      {
         "airport_code":"ABJ",
         "city":"ABJ",
         "country":"CI",
         "name":"Port Bouet Airport",
         "city_name":"Abidjan",
         "country_name":"Cote d'Ivoire",
         "lat":5.261390209,
         "lon":-3.926290035,
         "alt":21,
         "utc_offset":0.0
      },
      {
         "airport_code":"ABV",
         "city":"ABV",
         "country":"NG",
         "name":"Nnamdi Azikiwe International Airport",
         "city_name":"Abuja",
         "country_name":"Nigeria",
         "lat":9.006790161,
         "lon":7.263169765,
         "alt":1123,
         "utc_offset":1.0
      },
      ........ 
   ]
}
```

**GET /airports/{airport_code}**

**GET /flights/**

```
{
    "total_count": 898,
    "items": [
        {
            "flight_number": "ZG6304",
            "aircraft_registration": "ZGAJG",
            "departure_airport": "BAH",
            "arrival_airport": "LHR",
            "scheduled_departure_time": "2020-01-01T20:50:00",
            "scheduled_takeoff_time": "2020-01-01T21:00:00",
            "scheduled_landing_time": "2020-01-02T03:00:00",
            "scheduled_arrival_time": "2020-01-02T03:10:00"
        },
        {
            "flight_number": "ZG6311",
            "aircraft_registration": "ZGAJH",
            "departure_airport": "CDG",
            "arrival_airport": "FRA",
            "scheduled_departure_time": "2020-01-01T06:45:00",
            "scheduled_takeoff_time": "2020-01-01T06:55:00",
            "scheduled_landing_time": "2020-01-01T07:50:00",
            "scheduled_arrival_time": "2020-01-01T08:00:00"
        },
        ........
    ]
}
```

I am working on building an airport arrivals and departures web application using the above data. My idea was to try and combine the data of /fligts/ and /airports/ API call based on `departure_airport` and `arrival_airport` to be able to have more information inside a single array such as information about the `city_name`, `lat`, `long` etc. to visualize the data. I wanted to know a good approach for solving this issue keeping in mind the computational overhead of filtering and merging large sets of data. I looked into using RxJS but I have not worked with it before to be sure if it would provide a good solution

Comment: It would be better to make the mapping in the backend, as go through each item in "airports api" list and make a request to get "/airports/{airport_code} api", This will be a heavy operation on the front-end and it will take a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to convert the airports array to an object. After you can access the airports by keys.

```
const airports = {
  total_count: 269,
  items: [
    {
      airport_code: 'ABJ',
      city: 'ABJ',
      country: 'CI',
      name: 'Port Bouet Airport',
      city_name: 'Abidjan',
      country_name: "Cote d'Ivoire",
      lat: 5.261390209,
      lon: -3.926290035,
      alt: 21,
      utc_offset: 0.0,
    },
    {
      airport_code: 'ABV',
      city: 'ABV',
      country: 'NG',
      name: 'Nnamdi Azikiwe International Airport',
      city_name: 'Abuja',
      country_name: 'Nigeria',
      lat: 9.006790161,
      lon: 7.263169765,
      alt: 1123,
      utc_offset: 1.0,
    },
  ],
};

const mappedAirports = airports.items.reduce(
  (result, airport) =>
    (result = { ...result, [airport.airport_code]: airport }),
  {}
);

console.log(mappedAirports);
```

Output:

```
{"ABJ":{"airport_code":"ABJ","city":"ABJ","country":"CI","name":"Port Bouet Airport","city_name":"Abidjan","country_name":"Cote d'Ivoire","lat":5.261390209,"lon":-3.926290035,"alt":21,"utc_offset":0},"ABV":{"airport_code":"ABV","city":"ABV","country":"NG","name":"Nnamdi Azikiwe International Airport","city_name":"Abuja","country_name":"Nigeria","lat":9.006790161,"lon":7.263169765,"alt":1123,"utc_offset":1}}
```